# How can I solve the "return true if water drank day bigger than 4 of each week in multi-dimensional array"

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Fix the function `adequateWaterTracker`. `adequateWaterTracker` should return
true if ALL the the weeks in the calendar array having more days in the week
that you drank water than you didn't.

For example, in this week, [0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 0], each day represents how many
cups of water you drank that day. In this example, there were only 3 days where
you drank at least one cup of water.

A calendar is represented by multiple weeks,
[[0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 0], [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1]].

If you drank water for at least 4 days of water for every week in the calendar,
then return true. Otherwise, return false.

I know that I should add statement like if every week water counter is more than it will 4 return true. But I couldn't. Where should I add it and How?

```
function adequateWaterTracker(calendar) {
  let noWater = 0;
  let water = 0;
debugger
  for (let i = 0; i < calendar.length; i++) {
    const week = calendar[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < week.length ; j++) {
      const day = week[j];
      if (day=== 0 ) {
        noWater++;
      } else {
        water++;
      }

    }

  }
return noWater < water
}

const calendar1 = [
  [0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 0],
  [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1],
];

console.log(adequateWaterTracker(calendar1)); // false

const calendar2 = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
];

console.log(adequateWaterTracker(calendar2)); // false

const calendar3 = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
];

console.log(adequateWaterTracker(calendar3)); // true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `every` method to check if all the week array achieves a specific condition and on each week array, you can `filter` to filter the days which is more or equal to one, then get the length of the array and check if it's equal or more than 4.

```js
const adequateWaterTracker = (calendar) => calendar.every(w => w.filter((d) => d >= 1).length >= 4)

const calendar1 = [
  [0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 0],
  [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1],
];

console.log(adequateWaterTracker(calendar1)); // false

const calendar2 = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
];

console.log(adequateWaterTracker(calendar2)); // false

const calendar3 = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
];

console.log(adequateWaterTracker(calendar3)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use a **boolean** state
here I have used `prevRow` to keep a check on previous row using boolean
we know after iterating the **inner** array we need to check **noWater < water** ? right ?
so we can add if block outside of inner for loop and check

- if **noWater < water**
- make prevRow = false and break
- or **reset** the noWater and water for the next iteration

`

```
function adequateWaterTracker(calendar) {
    let noWater = 0;
    let water = 0;
    let prevRow = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < calendar.length; i++) {
        const week = calendar[i];
        for (let j = 0; j < week.length; j++) {
            const day = calendar[i][j];
            if (day === 0) {
                noWater++;
            } else {
                water++;
            }
        }
        // check
        if (noWater > water) {
            prevRow = false;
            break;
        }
        noWater = 0;
        water = 0;
    }
    return prevRow;
}
```

`

- the solution given by mina looks really good and follows a functional approach
- as a beginner-friendly approach adding my input here even though I took some time to figure it out, hope it will help
- specifically, the key learning part is using a boolean state and understanding how values should be reset in loops

thank you